# javascript click button function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button

I am creating an attendance system for our staff system programming in PHP and JS.

I have a button called ADD - to add new record 
and EDIT button to edit the record inserted

I need to do something so when staff will record time-start by clicking ADD button, I want to hide time-end and shows when click only EDIT button >

HOW to do that ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add_button').click(function() {
    $('#product_form')[0].reset();
    $('.modal-title').text("Add record");
    $('#action').val("Add");
    $('#operation').val("Add");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Add record form in fact it same when click edit same form but I need to hide time-end when click ADD .

<div id="productModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form method="post" id="product_form">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">ADD NEW RECORD</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" dir="rtl">
          <label>STAFF NAME</label>
          <input type="text" name="attendance_name" id="attendance_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['fname'];?> <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['lname'];?>" />
          <br />
          <label>ID NO</label>
          <input type="text" name="attendance_username" id="attendance_username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username'];?>" />
          <br />
          <label>TIME LOGIN </label>
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo " " . date("h:i:s ");
         ?>" name="attendance_start" id="attendance_start" class="form-control" />
          <br />


          <label>TIME LOGOFF </label>

          <h1>Here I need to hide input for add record and show when click button EDIT</h1>
          <br />


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="hidden" name="attendance_id" id="attendance_id" />
          <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" />
          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please EDIT, then  click ***Edit above snippet*** and add relevant HTML and script you have tried - this is not a PHP problem

Comment: yes this is not PHP , this in JS language but i am not pro with it

Comment: That may be so. But we cannot help unless we see the relevant minimal HTML and whatever script you have tried. SO is not a "write my code for me for free" site. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: There is no edit button in your code

Comment: there is a js code for edit my project is ready but i need to add this function only